# Does"grinning from ear to ear" mean they have a big smile?

Tags: expressions

like this ?[image: enter image description here smile]
I never heard it before.

Answer (score 4):

To grin from ear to ear is idiomatic, the smile on a person's face when feeling elation.

[**grin from ear to ear**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grin+from+ear+to+ear)

> *to smile a very wide, beaming smile.*
>
> She was grinning from ear to ear as she accepted the prize.
>
> We knew Timmy was happy because he was grinning from ear to ear.

**grin/smile from ear to ear**

> *to look extremely happy (usually in continuous tenses)*
>
> We've had a fantastic response,' he said, grinning from ear to ear.

**grin from ear to ear** *also* smile from ear to ear

> *to give a very big smile*
>
> He was grinning from ear to ear, as if he had just won the lottery.

Just remember that it's that 'big' smile when a person feels extremely delighted or happy.

Answer (score 1):

No, "[**grin**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grin)" means:

> To smile broadly, often baring the teeth, as in amusement, glee, embarrassment, or other strong emotion.

*"Grinning from ear to ear"* simply means that you have a wide smile on your face, usually out of amusement or satisfaction. Usually an ulterior reason behind the smile will give it a reason, say for example,

> you sedated your neighbor's dog, the one that barks all night long.

[image]

Comment: This is incorrect.

Comment: @user3932000 Please provide reasons as to why you believe this is incorrect, instead of just saying that the answer is wrong. Maybe I can learn something from it.

Comment: "Grinning from ear to ear" is a common expression that just exaggerates the original verb of "grinning." I have not found any definition that the phrase suggests an ulterior motive, and I have never in my life heard the phrase used in that way by itself.

Comment: @user3932000 But I have. A grin is a wide smile which may, like any other reason to smile, will have a reason behind it. There's nothing more to what I have mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Then that might be a limited, local nuance, because most English speakers do not understand the phrase to imply ulterior motives or malice.